# Do all ETFs have an expiry date similar to SPY?

Tags: united-states, etf, etn

Quote from [The Fate of the World's Largest ETF Is Tied to 11 Random Millennials](https://www.bloombergquint.com/markets/meet-the-spy-11-kids-with-250-billion-riding-on-their-lives):

> SPY as we know it will cease to be on Jan. 22, 2118

Also [chaikinanalytics](https://www.chaikinanalytics.com/the-spy-etf/) says that [SPY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SPDR_S%26P_500_Trust_ETF) "has an official expiration date of January 22, 2118".

So my question is: Do all ETFs/ETNs have an expiry date or is SPY special?

Comment: Related: [Why will SPY terminate in 2118?](https://money.stackexchange.com/q/125602)

Comment: "Do all ETFs have an expiry date similar to SPY?" No. SPY is structured as a Unit Investment Trust (UIT). UITs have to have a termination date. Newer ETFs in the US are not structured as UITs, and so do not have termination dates.

Comment: @Flux I think you answered the question and answer seems that 'Some ETF has expiration date not all"

Is there any other ETF that has expiry date ?

Comment: QQQ has a mandatory termination date in 2124. You can get all this information by reading prospectuses.

Comment: @Flux Can SPY or QQQ's termination date be extended ? You used the word ** mandatory ** does it mean that QQQ will cese to exist but SPY can be extened ?

Comment: Read the prospectus. It will tell you all the details about termination.

Answer (score 5):

> Do all ETFs have an expiry date similar to SPY?

No. SPY is structured as a [Unit Investment Trust (UIT)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_investment_trust). UITs have to have a termination date. Newer ETFs in the US are not structured as UITs, and so do not have termination dates.